# How do you update Xcode on OSX to the latest version?

Tags: xcode, macos, homebrew

What is the easiest way to update Xcode on OSX?

I see this in the terminal:

```
$ brew install xxxxxxx
Warning: Your Xcode (4.3.3) is outdated
Please install Xcode 4.6.
```

But when I go to open up `Xcode > Preferences > Downloads`, it says there are no updates?

Answer (score 379, accepted):

1. Open up App Store

   [image]
2. Look in the top right for the updates section (may also be in lefthand column "Updates"..)

   [image]
3. Find Xcode & click Update
   [image]

Comment: Just want to also note that this will only show as an update if you installed your version directly from the App Store. However, if you installed it from elsewhere, you will need to re-download the entire new version of Xcode.

Comment: Is there a terminal solution to forcing xcode to update? I let it update through the app store overnight and Xcode still did not get updated.

Comment: any idea with this case?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35202711/problems-with-xcode-7-2-1

Comment: In my case, I need to update twice, currently im updating it for the second time. Hope this is the last time I need to update. xcode 6.x to 7.2.1

Comment: No Xcode update shows up for me in the Updates section.  I've just updated from Yosemite to El Capitan and Xcode is currently version 7.2.  But need 7.3 to develop for my iPhone which now is on version 9.3 of iOS.

Comment: Just search for the xcode in the searchbox, there you will get the xcode with the option to update the xcode even if you not installed using appstore. It works for me in Yosemite

Comment: Searching for xcode on the search box and installing it worked on Sierra too

Comment: I had to upgrade my macOS first, then Xcode appeared in list of things to update

Comment: did mine never start updating or is there really no progress indicator?

Comment: Said I had to log in with appleid, and entered it, and it didn't work. It didn't say the id or password was wrong. When I made the password different on purpose, it did. It just loaded, and then sent me back to the username and password

Comment: Apple is so damn frustrating. The last several OS upgrades have broken so many things. Wasting hours trying to fix everything Mojave broke.

Comment: OK, I'm on Mojave 10.14.5 and my Xcode is 10.1. I see in AppStore the version history shows lastest version as 10.2.1, but still no suggestion to update from it, only OPEN is available, no matter if I try to search for it or whatever else, damn buggy piece of crap... I need this latest version to build my app!

Comment: How can I use another account in Appstore

Comment: The App Store does not show an update for Xcode 11.4, even though I am running 11.1

Comment: Today is Nov 16, the latest version was released at Nov 12. I still don't see any update in App Store.

Answer (score 126):

`softwareupdate --list` see the list of outdated software.

`softwareupdate --install --all` update all outdated software.

`softwareupdate --install <product name>` update the software you named.

Comment: Did not work for me on Sierra.  `softwareupdate --list
Software Update Tool

Finding available software
No new software available.`

Comment: Doesn't work on MacOS Catalina 10.15.1.  `softwareupdate --install Xcode` says `Xcode: No such update`

Answer (score 70):

Sometime I don't see the Xcode update in `Updates tab` in `AppStore`
So I search Xcode in AppStore
[image]

Then click update and it update

Comment: I think somehow the update is not detected after OS update, this solution worked for me.

Comment: I was asked to install Xcode all over again. Perhaps due to the High Sierra upgrade.. No idea. Had it installed before.

Comment: After an OS update, it was saying there were no updates, even though 12 was available and I was on 11.5.  I went to the app store and searched, it had an "open" button (not an "update" button).  But when I clicked into the details, it did have an "update" button.

Answer (score 66):

[image]

If attempting to download via the App Store leaves you with a little grey spinner and nothing actually happening, then you can go to :

#### https://developer.apple.com/download/more/

log in with your Apple Developer ID, and the latest Xcode should be available as a .zip download.

Comment: This only allows me to download xCode 9, I want to download 8.2.1 what should I do? @kris

Comment: @Avatar - that is strange, when I visit https://developer.apple.com/download/more/ and scroll down I can also see earlier versions, including 8.2.1 - maybe pursue this with Apple Help

Comment: I had captain when I update to high sierra problem has been solved. @kris

Comment: why appstore keeps hanging on this spinner? I'm sure it spins but actually doesnt do anything behind the wheel.

Comment: Keep in mind that it spun for about 5 minutes for me before downloading

Answer (score 37):

In my case (Xcode 6.1, iOS 8.2) I did not see the update in AppStore.
I found Xcode 6.2 for download and pressed "Install".
Then, it installed and asked for the update (more than 2 Gb).
Xcode 6.2 works correctly with iOS 8.2 and iOS 8.1.2

Hopefully this tip will help somebody else...

Comment: Good point. there was nothing in the AppStore for me, even though I'm on 6.0 instead of 7.0.

Comment: There was no update indicator for me either, had to find the update in the store manually.

Answer (score 20):

`xcode-select --install` worked for me

Answer (score 13):

Another best way to update and upgrade OSX development tools using command line is as follows:

Open terminal on OSX and type below commands. Try 'sudo' as prefix if you don't have admin privileges.

```
brew update
```

and for upgrading outdated tools and libraries use below command

```
brew upgrade
```

These will update all packages like node, rethinkDB and much more.

Also, `softwareupdate --install --all` this command also work best.

Important: Remove all outdated packages and free some space using the simple command.

```
brew cleanup
```

Comment: I had no updates seen by what other answers said. Only this worked! :)

Comment: does not work if you get the following Error: Your Xcode (n.n.n) is too outdated.

Comment: This answer is sadly not helping with the issue (XCode only updatable via Mac App Store)

Answer (score 7):

If you want the latest Beta, it will not be in the AppStore. Instead you have to login to https://developer.apple.com and download from there.

Answer (score 5):

I was able to fix the 'no updates' problem by going to the AppStore via the *developer's link*:

https://developer.apple.com/download/release/

Also, you might want to try this ['mas-cli-github'](https://github.com/mas-cli/mas) command,

```
$ brew install mas

$ mas list
$ mas search Xcode
$ mas install <id> 

$ mas upgrade <id>
```

Answer (score 4):

Check https://xcodereleases.com/ where you can also download legacy versions.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this bugger too.

I was running an older version of Xcode (not compatible with ios 9.2) so I needed to update.

I spent hours on this and was constantly getting spinning wheel of death in the app store. Nothing worked. I tried CLI softwareupdate, updating OSX, everything.

I ultimately had to download AppZapper, then nuked XCode.

I went into the app store to download and it still didn't work. Then I rebooted.

And from here I could finally upgrade to a fresh version of xcode.

WARNING: AppZapper can delete all your data around Xcode as well, so be prepared to start from scratch on your profiles, keys, etc. Also per the other notes here, of course be ready for a 3-5 hour long downloading expedition...

Comment: Note once you zap xcode you'll have to reinstall dev tools: https://gist.github.com/gaquino/87bdf0e6e852e445c0489379d3e9732a

Answer (score 3):

You DO NOT need to upgrade Xcode.

Just open the file `/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/extend/os/mac/diagnostic.rb` ,

then remove this line `check_xcode_minimum_version` in the following function.

```
def fatal_build_from_source_checks
    %w[
      check_xcode_license_approved
      check_xcode_minimum_version //<-- this one
      check_clt_minimum_version
      check_if_xcode_needs_clt_installed
    ].freeze
    end
```

Then `brew install` should works fine.

Comment: Why do you assumed that he DO NOT need to upgrade XCode,  Apple Store consistently requires updates of Xcode builds, unless they do not allow you to upload app updates.

Answer (score 2):

I used the `Command_Line_Tools_OS_X_10.XX_for_Xcode_7.2.dmg` and therefore had to download the latest version from [here](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/).

Answer (score 0):

For me it was >41GB for the update to start. ~/Library contains a lot of cached content for mail, browsers, etc...you can safely remove those. Remove big apps too, like iMovie..you can always install it back later

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find the updates in the app store. I ran the following code: "sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools", entered my macbook password, and then "xcode-select --install"

Answer (score 0):

If you have `fastlane` then you can run `fastlane snapshot reset_simulators` to remove all your simulators and add a bunch more.