# Max version of Cordova on xcode 4.5

Tags: cordova, osx-lion, xcode4.5, requirements

Hi i being asked to develop a Phonegap / Cordova app. I have mac mini2,1 mid 2007 processor 1.83 Ghz intel C2D Memory 2 GB with OSX Lion 10.7.5. what max CLI version of Cordova i can install?
i have tried to install Cordova 4.0 its says min xcode 4.6 is required. and can i upgrade xcode 4.5 to 4.6. do i have to upgrade Mac osx using this hardware?

Comment: right now you need xcode 5 to submit the apps, and in a few days (1st february) you'll need xcode 6, so buy a new mac, the new mac mini is cheap or you can buy a mac mini 2009, it can be updated to the latest OS X.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is generally a good idea to have the latest version in use when you have no other restrictions. For that reason, I would recommend you to follow [these steps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15417752/1744702) provided by user *jjn*. I do not think you need to upgrade your hardware nor the OS X for this purpose since working with Cordova doesn't require that much of computation power.