# Problems with Xcode 7.2.1

Tags: xcode, app-store

just install the new version of Xcode (7.2.1), he took a little longer than expected.

[image]

But when it finished and run the xcode continues with version 7.1.1

[image]

I thought it would be solved by restarting the Mac, but no.

Any idea what can be spent? or happened to me to be done?

***!EDITED!***

My MAC version.

[image]

My xcode options

[image]

My applications

[image]

Comment: You might be having 2 Xcode installed. Try to open from Applications.

Comment: @Ashutosh Dave thanks for your time. Update question with screenshot of the xcode options.

Comment: Yeah you must have more than one version of Xcode installed.  Check how you are opening it.

Comment: @trojanfoe I have looked everywhere and can not find other than the 7.1.1 version that I have, I understand that when upgrading through appStore never leaves 2 versions. The only way this could happen is if you manually install a beta version

Comment: Yes; how are you starting Xcode?  Having you tried going to `/Applications` in *Finder* and starting `Xcode` from there?

Comment: I have tried every way I could think of. Right click and open with the icon directly from the Finder, also from applications. I updated the question with a new screenshot

Comment: My problem is Xcode 7.2.1 always reinstall components, every time I start it...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem. I installed 4GB large 7.2.1 version of Xcode from the AppStore over an existing 7.2 version, and whichever way I was launching Xcode it was always the same old 7.2 popping up. What was worse I could not download 7.2.1 again, as AppStore app was not showing Install button anymore, but rather Launch button instead (like it was installed).

Finally I found a solution. I went to [Downloads for Apple Developers](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/) site (a login to a developer account was required), I dowloaded [Xcode_7.2.1.dmg](http://adcdownload.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Xcode_7.2.1/Xcode_7.2.1.dmg) 4.7GB large from there, launched an installation... which successfully replaced the older 7.2 version of Xcode.

Comment: Thanks friend, these people believe that one is dumb and never ever had upgraded a xcode and say it is problem between the computer and the seat. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Another answer suggests installing Xcode via a Developer Member Center download. I'd like to caution against this, and suggest an alternative approach.

Shortly before Xcode 7 became available, I upgraded an Xcode 6 installation to 6.4 by using the download. I did this to save download time for upgrading multiple machines (I put the installer on a flash drive). I subsequently discovered that using the downloaded installer broke tracking the version history in the App Store, and I was no longer able to upgrade via the App Store. Also, I was no longer notified of pending Xcode updates via the MAS "Updates" panel.

So a possible consequence for you may be that the App Store may not be able to handle your future Xcode updates, or even notify you when an update is pending.

What I ended up doing was deleting my then-current Xcode installation (I used AppDelete to get all of the components of the installation), and starting from scratch using the App Store. I recommend doing the same.  Probably the best way to start is to try deleting Xcode via Launchpad. But if that doesn't work (say, it doesn't delete all versions if you still have multiple versions), try AppDelete or a similar app.

I should note that one reason I used the download to upgrade Xcode 6 was that I'd done so previously *without* breaking the App Store's ability to track Xcode's version history.  Whether that previous behavior was a fluke, or whether the later behavior (losing the version history) was a fluke, I can't say.

If you've already installed via the Member Center installer, you can check to see if you'll have this problem by looking up Xcode in MAS. If the store shows you have the version you manually installed, then all is well (probably!). If not, either you'll have to keep track of updates by yourself, or you should re-establish MAS version tracking by deleting Xcode and starting from scratch via MAS.  I'd be interested to learn whether the store is tracking your manual installation.