# Homebrew saying Xcode is outdated

Tags: xcode, command-line, homebrew

I'm trying to perform an install of a package with Homebrew, but when I try to run the install I am getting the following error:

> Error: Your Xcode (7.3.1) is outdated.
>   Please update to Xcode 8.0 (or delete it).
>   Xcode can be updated from the App Store.

*I would like to keep Xcode 7.3.1 on this machine* since I have Xcode 8 on another machine, and am using this one for older projects.

I have found a similar post on SO, but the recommended solution to set `export TRAVIS=1` doesn't seem to work for me. Hoping someone has a fix or a workaround I may use. Here are some more of my specifics:

```
Xcode 7.3.1
Homebrew 1.0.8-135-g4284b82
macOS Sierra 10.12 (16A323)
```

If anything other specifics needed, please let me know.

Thanks guys!

Comment: You can always have Xcode 7.3.1 **and** 8.0 on the same machine. You can switch the 'default' Xcode with the command line tool `xcode-select`.

Comment: To keep older versions of Xcode, you need to explicityl download the DMGs form Apple website and install them manually. The copy of Xcode that was downloaded from the store becomes the "target for update" to the AppStore app, and is overwritten everytime you update from the store, as far as I know

Comment: for those who might end up here, the `xcode-select --install` installed the command line tools and solved my problem.

Comment: Strangely enough I got this error again and my above solution did not help! so I ended up using [App Cleaner & Uninstaller](https://nektony.com/how-to/uninstall-xcode-on-mac) uninstalling xcode completely.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

So as @NicolasMiari mentioned in a comment above, the fix to my issue ended up having to have both Xcode 7 and Xcode 8 on my machine. I went on the apple developer site, downloaded Xcode 8, saved it to my documents and then used:

```
sudo xcode-select -switch ~/Documents/Xcode.app/
```

and then ran my brew install which worked as expected. Afterwards I ran:

```
sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/
```

to switch back to Xcode 7.3.1.

Hope this helps someone else, and thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: Hi, I had storage issue so I don't want to upgrade my Xcode. is it possible using brew without updating xcode?

Comment: I haven't tried to use Homebrew without having Xcode installed, so I honestly am not sure the answer to that. Are you getting that error without having Xcode installed currently?

Comment: actually my problem is, my homebrew won't allow me to install something, and require me to upgrade my Xcode first. So i want to pass this warning that blocked me to install

Comment: Faced the same issue today with Xcode 8.3.3 and Xcode 9.0 (beta), and this helped to resolve it - had to use `sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/` for brew install to proceed

Comment: What should I do if I have only one Xcode 8 installed and it is too outdated? I don't want to delete the current Xcode, neither I want to install Xcode 9

Comment: Thanks, @georgeH ! This was driving me crazy for a while now.

Comment: To download older version of XCode from Apple, you have to sign into a Developer account in their Downloads section - https://developer.apple.com/download/more/?=xcode (linked from the [XCode Resources](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/resources/) page).

Answer (score 69):

Just do as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56252014/2109878)

Depending on your CPU type, open the following file:

- Apple Silicon chip: `/opt/homebrew/Library/Homebrew/extend/os/mac/diagnostic.rb`
- Intel chip: `/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/extend/os/mac/diagnostic.rb`

then delete this line `check_xcode_minimum_version` in the following function.

```rb
def fatal_build_from_source_checks
  %w[
    check_xcode_license_approved
    check_xcode_minimum_version
    check_clt_minimum_version
    check_if_xcode_needs_clt_installed
  ].freeze
end
```

Then `brew install` works fine.

Comment: I tried to comment it out by adding a `#` like `# check_xcode_minimum_version`, but that didn't work. Removing the line entirely (like you said) worked.

Comment: You can also find the function (e.g. `def check_xcode_minimum_version`) and put a `return` in the beginning — easier to revert when done.

Comment: Has to remove from `fatal_setup_build_environment_checks` too (not only from `fatal_build_from_source_checks`)

Comment: On M1 or Apple Silicon, this path is `/opt/homebrew/Library/Homebrew/extend/os/mac/diagnostic.rb` instead.

Answer (score 5):

1. according to https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/issues/4957 outdated home-brew could cause this problem, `brew update-reset` fix it.
2. if step 1 does not work, reinstall homebrew with 
   `/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"`

Answer (score 3):

Two options:

1. The best option is to update your xcode first, then follow [@George H's recommendation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40297388/4424636) above:

> So as @NicolasMiari mentioned in a comment above, the fix to my issue ended up having to have both Xcode 7 and Xcode 8 on my machine. I went on the apple developer site, downloaded Xcode 8, saved it to my documents and then used:
>
> ```
> sudo xcode-select -switch ~/Documents/Xcode.app/
> ```
>
> and then ran my brew install which worked as expected. Afterwards I ran:
>
> ```
> sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/
> ```
>
> to switch back to Xcode 7.3.1.

2. Set the `xcode-select` to the path of your CommandLineTools.

   ```
   sudo xcode-select --switch /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
   ```

   As explained here, .[Homebrew without Xcode](https://shawnliu.me/post/homebrew-without-xcode/)

Both options work well.

Answer (score 2):

Renaming worked for me:

`Xcode` -> `Xcode-old`
`Xcode-beta` -> `Xcode`

Comment: This is the easiest solution I found. +1 (y)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error:

```
brew install heroku
==> Installing heroku from heroku/brew
Error: Your Xcode (14.1) is too outdated.
Please update to Xcode 15.1 (or delete it).
Xcode can be updated from the App Store.
```

I opened App Store and searched 'xcode', instead of saying 'Open', the button said 'Update', indicating I had previously installed xcode via App Store (as opposed to via command line or some other means). As that was the case, I clicked 'Update', waited half an hour for it to download (3.4GB) and update, and when it was finished `brew install heroku` worked.

Answer (score -7):

Run this code in terminal

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)" < /dev/null 2> /dev/null ; brew install caskroom/cask/brew-cask 2> /dev/null
```

Then try running below code,

```
brew install jenkins
```

Hope this solves

Comment: How exactly does that fix the OP's error message?