# Can I debug iOS 14 on Mojave 14.6 with xcode 11?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos-mojave, ios14

My Mac version is Mojave 14.6, and if I don't upgrade to Catalina, is it possible to debug app on device of iOS 14 on xcode 11?

If not , maybe i won't upgrade my iPhone to iOS 14...

Comment: No, you can't run on iOS 14 using Xcode 11.

Comment: Its require macOS 10.15.4 or later and XCode 12 to debug app on iOS 14

Comment: Finally, I upgrade my iPhone to iOS 14 and upgrade my mac to Catalina 10.15.7. Everything works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is important is the version of XCode.  If you are using XCode 11, then you can only deploy to iOS 13 or lower.  Definitely don't upgrade to iOS 14 if you want to stay with XCode 11.

This is especially important if you are just learning iOS development and your resources and sample code references XCode 11.  Upgrading to XCode 12 might make some of the sample code or instructions not work anymore. Best you complete your learning and then upgrade.  Once you are proficient, you can upgrade and you should be able to fix any changes necessary to support the new version of XCode. Also possibly the original author will have updated their learning material as well.

Comment: "If you are using XCode 11, then you can only deploy to iOS 13 or lower" — does this apply even if using iOS 14 device support files with Xcode 11? For instance, I can debug on iOS 13.5 with Xcode 11.3.1 after copying device support files from a later version of Xcode (11.4?) that otherwise only runs on Catalina.

Comment: I tried the usual tricks with device support files, but with Xcode 11.7 on Mojave I had no success to debug on iOS 14. Only Xcode 12 works, and it requires Catalina.

Comment: Thanks @LPG, that's good to know. I didn't see your comment until now — feel free to @-mention me to generate notifications. I'm curious about Xcode 11.7 on Mojave. Here's what Apple says: "Xcode 11.7 requires a Mac running macOS Catalina 10.15.2 or later". How did you get it working on Mojave?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/63912493/1149188 for running Xcode 11.7 on Mojave.