# How to use Swift 5.3 with XCode 11.7 on MacOS Mojave?

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, xcode11

I was able to install Xcode 11.7 on my Mac Mojave by using this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63964688/5716308). But it's still using Swift 5.2.4. I want to upgrade my Swift compiler to v5.3. I downloaded then installed Swift v5.3 toolchain for Xcode from official the Swift's [repo](https://swift.org/download/#releases). The installation went just fine. However, when I checked the Swift version from Terminal app using `swiftc -v` command, it's still showing Swift v.5.2.4.

So, is there a way to make Xcode on Mojave using Swift v5.3 instead of the default Swift compiler (v5.2)?

Thank you.

---

Note: I don't want to use SwiftUI. I just want to use the new language features and compiler improvements from Swift 5.3.

Comment: What is your machine ? Xcode 12.1 requires an Intel-based Mac running macOS Catalina 10.15.4 or later

Comment: @LeoDabus: I know. As I've said, I'm on Mojave. I don't want Xcode 12 nor swiftUI, I just want to use Swift 5.3 compiler with Xcode 11.7. Is it possible?

Comment: I haven't used 11.7. Why don't you update your machine to Catalina? What Mac are you using?

Comment: @LeoDabus: Because Catalina doesn't support my machine, obviously. So, do you have any solution?

Comment: Mine either but I installed Catalina anyway. Again what is your machine?

Comment: @LeoDabus: My machine is not relevant. The point is, how do I use swift 5.3 with xcode 11.7. That's all.

Comment: I can’t answer your question without knowing your machine