# AppCode found no simulators to run

Tags: ios, appcode

[image: AppCode found no simulators to run]

I open my project with AppCode, and it shows `Nothing to run on`.

I cannot figure out where to configure my simulators.

Need somebody to help me. Running my project with Xcode is fine.

Comment: In AppCode, when you go to Preferences -> Tools -> Xcode, what does it say?

Answer (score 4):

I've had this happen when I have more than one version of Xcode installed (AppStore & Beta versions).

What happened for me was I had my default Xcode set to the AppStore version, but I created a project with the beta version so the target OS was the latest iOS beta. When AppCode launches, it checks the simulators provided by the version of Xcode it is set to in `Preferences->Tools->Xcode->Selected Xcode` and if it doesn't find one that matches the target version or higher it will show 'Nothing to run on'.

For instance (I'm just making up hypothetical version numbers as an example), if you have Xcode 11.1 installed with the iOS 13.1 simulator runtime & AppCode is set to use Xcode 11.1 in the `Tools->Xcode` preferences, but you have Xcode 11.2-Beta installed, which includes the iOS 13.2 simulator runtime, and created a new project with it (or edited an existing project) and have the target iOS version set to 13.2, when you load the project in AppCode it will check the Xcode 11.1 installation for the 13.2 simulator runtime. Since it won't exist in that version of Xcode, AppCode will report 'Nothing to run on'.

To fix it, either change AppCode's Xcode Version, or change your projects target iOS version.

Answer (score 0):

It's solved after I upgrade my Xcode... Still don't know what happened to AppCode

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15417619/how-do-you-update-xcode-on-osx-to-the-latest-version/37044755

Answer (score -1):

Create a new scheme for run from build settings

Comment: What does that mean?