# How to solve error: missing binary operator before token "(" on mac?

Tags: python, c++, c, macos, gcc

I am currently trying to install [PySift](https://github.com/OpenMined/PySyft) inside a virtualenv on Mac. However, the Zstandard library results in an error when being installed.

```
In file included from /usr/include/Availability.h:236:0,
                     from /usr/include/stdlib.h:61,
                     from zstd/lib/compress/fse_compress.c:38:
    /usr/include/AvailabilityInternal.h:33:18: error: missing binary operator before token "("
     #if __has_include(<AvailabilityInternalPrivate.h>)
                      ^
    In file included from /usr/include/stdlib.h:61:0,
                     from zstd/lib/compress/fse_compress.c:38:
    /usr/include/Availability.h:497:18: error: missing binary operator before token "("
     #if __has_include(<AvailabilityProhibitedInternal.h>)
                      ^
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Most of the solutions I've seen on Stack Overflow usually suggest running `xcode-select --install`, but it did not work. Alternatively, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52509602/cant-compile-c-program-on-a-mac-after-upgrade-to-mojave) suggests to use the following command

```
open /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg
```

The command will open up a window that allows you to install the missing MacOS SDK. Yet, it still didn't work. After that, I realized I have not updated Xcode to the latest version. But even after updating, the error still appears. Lastly, I tried to use `brew`, like in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15417619/how-do-you-update-xcode-on-osx-to-the-latest-version), and do some updating in case there was some corrupted software that prevented the installation to be completed.

I've also checked [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21338385/what-does-the-compiler-error-missing-binary-operator-before-token-mean), and didn't find my answer because I was specifically trying to find out why `__has_include` before `(` resulted in an error.

In the end, it still did *not* work. I wonder if somebody can me point to what I was missing that caused the error?

Comment: `__has_include` is C++17 specific - if the build options select an earlier standard or you are using an older compiler version, it will not be recognised.  Include the compiler command line in the log.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does the compiler error "missing binary operator before token" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21338385/what-does-the-compiler-error-missing-binary-operator-before-token-mean)

Answer (score 2):

You are getting a syntax error from the preprocessor, b/c it doesn't recognize `__has_include` as a valid function-like macro.  That's because it is a c++17 specific directive.

You could work around by just removing that line (and the matching #endif) from the file.  If you get a compiler error about a missing include, remove the #include line too.

Comment: It seems this file `/usr/include/Availability.h` is readonly. Even with sudo. So you can't change the file, and therefore I stille have my problem, with building ruby 1.8.7 with rbenv on Mojave.