# Issue while building IOS app in visual studio

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error     The type 'CoreLocation.CLBeaconIdentityConstraint' (used as a
>   parameter in
>   CoreLocation.CLLocationManager/_CLLocationManagerDelegate.DidFailRangingBeacons)
>   is not available in iOS 12.2 (it was introduced in iOS 13.0). Please
>   build with a newer iOS SDK (usually done by using the most recent
>   version of Xcode).

Note: I did not face this issue before a day, suddenly I was getting this Error,Can anyone help out.

OS version : 10.14.5
 Xcode 10.2

Answer (score 1):

The latest version of Xcode is 11.3.1 and you are running 10.2.  The message you posted suggests using the most recent version.  Here is a post explaining how to upgrade Xcode: [How do you update Xcode on OSX to the latest version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15417619/how-do-you-update-xcode-on-osx-to-the-latest-version/37044755)

In all likelihood, some change you made to the app caused the need to upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

You recently use `_CLLocationManagerDelegate.DidFailRangingBeacons` in your project and it is only available in iOS 13.

While with XCode 10.2 you use, it uses sdk iOS 12.2. That method is not available under your current version of XCode so you get the error message.

Solution is update both your Visual-Studio and XCode to meet the iOS 13 SDK requirement.

Here is the [Visual Studio 2019 Release Notes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/release-notes)

Comment: I'm using vs 2017

Comment: You can also update your vs 2017 to the latest version.